# C# - Improving encapsulation of property in this example?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I know of the error "The accessibility modifier of the set accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer". I also know the solution. Just not in this very specific case.

Consider this example:

```
    internal virtual bool IsFocused
    {
        get
        {
            return isFocused;
        }
        protected set
        {
            isFocused = value;
        }
    }
    private bool isFocused;
```

It shows the error. I just don't know why. How is "protected" not less accessible than internal? What would be the solution to this problem? I tried putting "internal protected" instead, without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`protected` allows an inherting class to access it while `internal` does NOT - `internal` restricts access to the assembly itself - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, `protected` is **more** accessible than `internal`.  Recall that `internal` means "not visible outside of this assembly" (except through [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) access, which makes `internal` look like `public`), whereas `protected` means visible to all subclasses.

Comment: So what would be the solution?

Comment: The solution would depend on what you were trying to achieve in the first place.  Do you really need this property to be internal?  Perhaps you are trying to cram too many responsibilities into a single class/interface.  Maybe you can scope the 'internal' surface area and put it in a separate fully internal class while keeping the top-level class public.

Answer (score 5):

@bobbymcr is entirely right in his analysis. The solution would be to mark property as `internal protected`. In C# that means that it would be accessible both to derived classes **AND** to all classes from current assembly.

If you put `internal protected` to accessor method - that means that it is accessible to derived classes. But entire property is not, which causes the error. If you mark entire property as `internal protected` and accessor method as `protected` - everything is fine.

```
internal protected virtual bool IsFocused
{
    get
    {
        return isFocused;
    }
    protected set
    {
        isFocused = value;
    }
}
private bool isFocused;
```

Other option would be to introduce `protected` method that would be called in setter. Then you could mark entire property as `internal` and allow to override only that method.