# Properties and private set

Tags: c#, properties, private

Why does this code not work?

```
class Test
{
    int Abc { private set; get; }
}
```

What is the default access modifier for properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Property must be more restrictive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886514/c-sharp-property-must-be-more-restrictive)

Comment: @Saeed while similar I don't think that one's a dup.

Comment: @kenny, In the question I mentioned it, OP described the problem of this problem (and implicitly how to solve it). In fact simple search in SO helps the current OP to solve his/her problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Abc property must be public, protected or internal:

```
public int Abc { get; private set; }
```

In your case the property is private (because you haven't specified an access modifier) so it's already a private set. You cannot modify its value outside of the current class so it doesn't really make sense to declare a private setter in this case.

Comment: @Colder, you can. and it is already private. So it is meaningless to define a private setter for a private property. Nothing outside of the current class can modify its value anyway. It also cannot get its value because the property is private. In this case you don't use a property. You use a field: `private int Abc;`.

Answer (score 3):

Default access modifier for properties is private, as for any other member of a class. If you wish to make the setter less accessible you would need to make the property more accessible first and then put restriction on the setter.

```
class Test
{
    public int Abc1 { private set; get; }
    protected  int Abc2 { private set; get; }
    internal int Abc3 { private set; get; }
    protected internal int Abc4 { private set; get; }
}
```

Comment: By 'type', you need to exclude enums and interfaces, whose members are public by default.

Answer (score 3):

The default accessibility of all class members (including properties) is `private`; see [Accessibility Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx). The `private` before your `set` is redundant, thus the error. Your code would be semantically equivalent to the following:

```
class Test
{
    int Abc { get; set; }
}
```

You only need to specify a `private` access modifier for your `set` accessor when the property is more accessible; for example (a common scenario):

```
class Test
{
    public int Abc { get; private set; }
}
```